# Trying to create copy function in a vector class

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference, dynamic-allocation

I am working on implementing a vector class but cannot figure out how to write a function to copy one vector into another.

```
template <class T> class Vec {

public:
//TYPEDEFS
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;
    typedef unsigned int size_type;

//CONSTRUCTOS, ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR, & DESTRUCTOR
    Vec() {this->create(); }
    Vec(size_type n, const T& t = T()) { this->create(n, t); }
    Vec(const Vec& v) { copy(v); }
    Vec& operator=(const Vec& v);
    ~Vec() { delete [] m_data; }

//MEMBER FUNCTIONS AND OTHER OPERATORS
    T& operator[] (size_type i) { return m_data[i]; }
    const T& operator[] (size_type i) const { return m_data[i]; }
    void push_back (const T& t);
    iterator erase(iterator p);
    void resize(size_type n, const T& fill_in_value = T());
    void clear() { delete [] m_data; create(); }
    bool empty() const { return m_size == 0; }
    size_type size() const { return m_size; }

//ITERATOR OPERATIONS
    iterator begin() { return m_data; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return m_data; }
    iterator end() { return m_data + m_size; }
    const_iterator end() const { return m_data + m_size; }

private:
//PRIVATE MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    void create();
    void create(size_type n, const T& val);
    void copy(const Vec<T>& v);

//REPRESENTATION
    T *m_data;      //point to first location inthe allocated array
    size_type m_size;   //number of elements stored in the vector
    size_type m_alloc;  //number of array locations allocated, m_size <= m_alloc
};

//create an empty vector (null pointers everywhere)
template <class T> void Vec<T>::create() {
    m_data = NULL;
    m_size = m_alloc = 0;   //no memory allocated yet
}

//create a vector with size n, each location having the given value
template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(size_type n, const T& val) {
    m_data = new T[n];
    m_size = m_alloc = n;
    for (T* p = m_data; p != m_data + m_size; ++p)
        *p = val;
}   

//assign one vector to another, avoiding duplicate copying
template <class T> Vec<T>& Vec<T>::operator=(const Vec<T>& v) {
    if (this != &v) {
        delete [] m_data;
        this -> copy(v);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This is the first things I came up with:

```
template <class T> void Vec<T>::copy(const Vec<T>& v) {

     m_size = m_alloc = v.size();
     m_data = &v;

}
```

I got an error about incompatible types...OK, makes sense that they are incompatible.  So I take out the 'const' and now it works.

```
template <class T> void Vec<T>::copy(Vec<T>& v) {

     m_size = m_alloc = v.size();
     m_data = &v[0];

}
```

I am guessing this isn't entirely correct or good form. I'm not sure.  And now I get an error about the pointer being freed not having been allocated (but it compiles, runs, and copies the vector successfully at least now).  So I would say I am not really understanding passing variables/arrays/vectors/things by reference, and also dynamic allocation of memory.  My question is: how can I improve the copy function that I have written to either not compare two incompatible variables, or to successfully allocate the pointer dynamically to the new vector so that I don't get that malloc error?

Comment: You don't need to call `size()`. In a copy constructor, you can access the parameter's private variables, so `m_size = m_alloc = v.m_size` would be fine. Secondly, don't do `m_data = &v;`. You're supposed to copy the buffers, not take a reference.

Comment: What you're doing is not *copying* a vector, you are *sharing* a vector (this will probably cause double-frees and segmentation faults later).  If you want to actually copy a vector, you need to allocate the memory and copy all the elements over (with, say, `std::copy`).

Comment: If you really wanted to copy a vector, you could simply have cleared `this`, and in a loop, call push_back() for each element in the vector `v`.

Comment: Your `operator=` is faulty.  You deleted `m_data`, so if an exception is thrown attempting to allocate the memory again, you've corrupted your `this`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do deep-copy of the elements, not simply assign the pointer `m_data`:

```
// precondition: `m_data` is not allocated
template <class T> void Vec<T>::copy(const Vec<T>& v) {
    m_data = new T[v.size()];
    m_size = m_alloc = v.size();
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < m_size; ++ii)
        m_data[ii] = v[ii];
}
```

Comment: @jld There is a small issue with this answer, and that is that if `new` throws an exception, the `m_size` and `m_alloc` members for `this` are hosed.  The allocation should occur before any of the other lines, so that an exception won't cause an issue.

Answer (score 3):

For your copy-constructor to be safe it needs to fail when the copy can't be made.

```
Vec<T>::Vec(const Vec<T>& o):m_size(o.m_size), m_alloc(o.m_size), m_data(new T()){
    std::copy( o.m_data, o.m_data+o.m_size, m_data);
}
```

The copy-constructor should be able to replace any *Vec<T>::copy* member.

The assignment is easily handled by introducing a swap function. This is exception safe.

```
void Vec<T>::swap(Vec<T>& rhs){
   std::swap(m_data, rhs.m_data);
   std::swap(m_size, rhs.m_size);
   std::swap(m_capacity, rhs.m_capacity);
}
```

With the exception safe *Copy & swap & idiom* it becomes:

```
Vec<T>& Vec<T>::operator = (const Vec<T>& rhs){
   Vec<T> cpy=rhs;
   swap( this, cpy);
   return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is an issue with exception safety with the previous answer given.  The simple fix is to allocate first.

```
// precondition: `m_data` is not allocated
template <class T> void Vec<T>::copy(const Vec<T>& v) {
    m_data = new T[v.size()];
    m_size = m_alloc = v.size();
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < m_size; ++ii)
        m_data[ii] = v[ii];
}
```

The other issue with your code is `operator=`, which is not exception safe.  You deleted `m_data` before allocating again with `new[]`.  If `new[]` fails, you've corrupted your object.

Once you have the fix to `copy` as above, then `operator =` can be written in terms of the copy constructor:

```
template <class T> Vec<T>& Vec<T>::operator=(const Vec<T>& v) 
{
    // construct a temporary
    Vec<T> temp = v;

    // set the members
    m_size = m_alloc = temp.size();
    delete [] m_data;
    m_data = temp.m_data;

    // Now set temp.m_data to 0, so that destruction of temp doesn't delete
    // our memory
    temp.m_data = 0;
    return *this;
}
```

Basically, we construct a temporary from `v`, delete the `this->m_data` and then assign the elements of `temp` to `this`.  Then we remove the guts of `temp` by setting the `temp.m_data` data to NULL.  This needs to be done so that when `temp` dies, we don't want to `delete` the data we assigned to `this`.

Note that if the first line `Vec<T> temp = v;` throws an exception, no harm to `this` is 
done, thus exception safety is provided.

Here is the copy/swap idiom, as suggested by `Captain Giraffe`:

```
template <class T> class Vec {
//...
  void swap(Vec<T>& left, Vec<T>& right);
//..
};

template <class T> void Vec<T>::swap(Vec<T>& left, Vec<T>& right)
{
    std::swap(left.m_size, right.m_size);
    std::swap(left.m_alloc, right.m_alloc);
    std::swap(left.m_data, right.m_data);
}

template <class T> Vec<T>& Vec<T>::operator=(const Vec<T>& v)
{
    // construct a temporary
    Vec<T> temp = v;
    swap(*this, temp);
    return *this;
}
```

The difference here is that we're swapping the members of `temp` with `this`.  Since `temp` will now contain the pointer that `this` used to have, when `temp` dies, it will be calling `delete` on this "old" data.

Comment: Why not a Copy&Swap? Idiomatic, exeption safe, elegant and reuses preexisting code.

Comment: When will temp die?  What determines that?

Comment: @jld - `When will temp die? What determines that?`  That's the beauty of the destructor.  When `temp` goes out of scope (which is at function termination, i.e. the final `}`), the destructor for `temp` is called.